# Как создать Popup меню в android?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, возникла необходимость создать **popup**-меню. Порылся, нигде примеров нет, только на  [офф. сайте](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu), но проблема в том, что это меню для API не меньше 11, а мне нужно запустить на 7. Как можно сделать что-то подобное?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, почему вы не можете использовать [PopupWindow][1]. Оно поддерживание с level 1.


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: popupwindow да, но это не popup menu, я решил уже этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, здесь описано именно то, что вам нужно: [Создание QuickAction диалогов в Android](http://habrahabr.ru/post/103582/) +)

Comment: спасибо, воспользовался этой идеей!

Answer (score 1):

Просто используйте вместо PopupMenu - AlertDialog. Для обычно меню бывает достаточно варианта со списком. Подробнее здесь: [Creating an AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog).

Comment: дело в том, что мне нужно меню наподобие popup, чтобы при нажатию на кнопку на активити, вылазило как бы их кнопки

Comment: Тогда попробуйте взять исходник PopupMenu из последнего среза кода и добавить в свой проект, вполне возможно, что больших изменений доводок не потребуется.

Comment: Дело в том, что по той ссылке, которую я дал, нужен API>=11

Comment: Это понятно. Просто выдираете исходник из последней версии кода, добавляете в свой проект, а потом меняете так, чтобы все компилировалось и работало. Там строк 200 - может не сильно и переделывать потребуется.

P.S. Но проще взять Dialog.

Comment: Мне кажется, это слишком для меню :D
Я надеялся, что кто-то это уже делали, потому что во многих приложениях такое есть, я не думаю, что предложенным вами способом все пользовались.

Answer (score 0):

`PopupMenu` по сути это же обычный `Spinner`. Ну так и возьмите привяжите к какой-нить кнопке, чтобы выскакивал `Spinner`, не?

Comment: к сожалению, мне не подходит spinner, но все равно спасибо.